# Pile-up in LHC collisions and number of signal events

Tags: particle-physics, large-hadron-collider

When counting the number of accepted events in a collider experiment, what is the effect of not considering the pile-up effect in e.g. proton-proton collisions at the LHC?

Comment: Are you counting an 'event' as a collision or a bunch crossing? Pile-up means there are multiple collisions per bunch crossing, so if you take 'event' to mean collision then you will undercount if you ignore pileup and just count accepted bunch crossings. PS @innisfree re: the first edit, I'm a bit confused why mentions of the LHC are added.

Comment: Which other colliders suffered from pileup? Actually maybe a few and  mentioning LHC wasn't a good idea

Comment: It is more of a problem in LHC though http://home.fnal.gov/~mrenna/lutp0613man2/node189.html

Comment: the data are gauged with the monte carlo simulation of the experimental conditions, and "pile ups" are taken into account, together with all experimental confusions and gray areas

Comment: If you were to mistake a pile-up for a single collision, you would violate the conservation of energy-momentum for a start… after which nothing matters anymore!